# HashWithIndifferentAccess error after improving the look of my form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I had a perfectly working signup process (and a bunch of other forms inside the app too), and recently decided to make it look better using a range of bootstrap 3 classes. Unfortunately, all the forms that I've now updated to look better refuse to work - they just throw the following in my debug-dump:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: "✓"
authenticity_token: fKx7bdWtC7bmBKMRF3ivwBlmJXzrcWJ16dYYOfNLBC0=
organization: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
organization_name: W
users: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
name: K
email: w@k.com
password: password
password_confirmation: password
organization_id: ''
commit: Create my account
controller: organizations
action: new
```

Beforehand this same set of info would have set up an Organization named "W", with a user names "K" and a password set to "password" - then re-routed the new user to their Organization page. I can't for the life of me work out why this HashWithIndifferentAccess issue has come about (it's the same issue on all controllers that I've updated the form html/css for).

Anyway, here's the relevant organization controller:

```
def new
 @organization = Organization.new
 @organization.users.build
end
```

organization model code:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true 
 has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization
 has_many :companies, :inverse_of => :organization
 has_many :products, :inverse_of => :organization
 has_many :competitors, :inverse_of => :organization
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
 after_create :set_admin
```

And here's the form.html.erb - where I suspect the error lies given this is all I've changed today:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Sign up!</h1>
<div class="row">
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="well">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <%= form_for(@organization) do |f| %>
                            <%= render 'shared/org_error_messages' %>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <%= f.label :organization_name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                <div class ="col-md-8">
                                <%= f.text_field :organization_name, :placeholder => "Who do you work for?" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <%= f.fields_for :users, @organization.users_for_form do |user| %>
                                 <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <%= user.label :name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                                    <%= user.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What's your name?" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <%= user.label :email, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                                    <%= user.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <%= user.label :password, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                                    <%= user.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Enter password - minimum 6 characters" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <%= user.label :password_confirmation, "Repeat Password", :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                                    <%= user.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Repeat password" %>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                                <%= user.hidden_field :organization_id, input_html: {value: @organization.id} %>
                            <% end %>
                            <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
                            <% end %>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Having read another answer about this here I've already tried changing the form_for(@organization) line to "form_for(:organization)" and it has the same functionality.

FWIW some of my rspec tests blew up and showed this error to me, whereas others did not. The Organization/User signup tests still seem to suggest I can create a user through this screen - I've included them below too, just in case it helps someone to understand the error.

describe "signup" do

```
before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user"  do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  it "should not create an Organization" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(Organization, :count)
  end
  describe "after submission" do
    before { click_button submit }

    it { should have_title('Sign up') }
    it { should have_content('error') }
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
    before do

        fill_in "Organization name", with: "Example Org"
        fill_in "Name",             with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",            with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",         with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Repeat Password",  with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

  it "should create an Organization" do
  expect { click_button submit }.to change(Organization, :count).by(1) 
end

  describe "after saving the user" do
    before { click_button submit }
    let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
    it {should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Thanks') }
    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
    end 
    end
end
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this is supposed to take the user to their Organization page upon signup, instead it re-renders the organizations new form again, without any errors on the field submissions.

Comment: I don't understand the "issue" here. Is the issue that the HashWithIndifferentAccess debug information or... what? I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: The issue is that the form no longer creates the object it is supposed to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for`already takes care of creating a `<form>`tag, so you're actually nesting a form within another form.

If you want to apply bootstrap classes to the form, use:

```
<%= form_for(@organization, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

and remove the `<form>` html tag.